# Accessing settings menu via browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, settings

Is it possible to access device settings from the browser on an mobile device using HTML5 and JavaScript?

I am trying to recreate something like in Android, where by you can launch an intent to show a specific settings page, using code similar to below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have been doing some searching and havn't been able to find anything. This to me suggests it isn't possible.

Comment: Sorry, should have made it more clear. The settings id like to access are the location settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access device settings from the browser on an mobile device using HTML5 and JavaScript?

Not reliably.

You could, in a scrap Android app, create your `Intent`, then [call `toUri()` on it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#toUri%28int%29) to give you a `Uri`, which you in turn convert to a `String` via `toString()`. You could then use that as the value on a hyperlink via copy and paste into your HTML code.

However, this assumes that the browser understands what to do when it encounters an `intent:` URL, and that is likely to vary by browser.

Comment: Well worth looking into, Thanks for the reply.